# Pygame, self is not defined

Tags: python, pygame, self

So I'm getting this error when I compile, I don't understand though because I've got 2 identical classes, one works fine the other throws out this error.

***if self.currentState2==1:
NameError: name 'self' is not defined***

```
class EnemyShip(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, (x, y), playerShip):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("enemy.png")
        self.image = self.image.convert()
        tranColor = self.image.get_at((1, 1))
        self.image.set_colorkey(tranColor)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.enemyX = float(x)
        self.enemyY = float(y)
        self.ship = playerShip
        self.count = 0
        self.currentState2 = 0

    def update(self):
        self.count += 1
        x_component = self.ship.rect.centerx-self.enemyX
        y_component = self.ship.rect.centery-self.enemyY
        distance = math.hypot(x_component, y_component)
        if distance < 100:
            self.currentState2 = 1
            print distance
        elif distance > 100:
            self.currentState2 = 0
            print "test2"


        if self.count < 600:
            self.caculateNextPosition()
            self.rect.center = (self.enemyX, self.enemyY)
        elif self.count < 600:
            self.caculateNextPositionEvade()
            self.rect.center = (self.enemyX, self.enemyY)
        else:
            self.count = 0    

    def caculateNextPosition(self):
        shipX = self.ship.rect.centerx
        shipY = self.ship.rect.centery
    if self.currentState2==1:
        if self.enemyY < shipY:
            self.enemyY += 4
        elif self.enemyY > shipY:
            self.enemyY -= 4

        if self.enemyX < shipX:
            self.enemyX += 4
        elif self.enemyX > shipX:
            self.enemyX -= 4
    elif self.currentState2==0: 
        if self.enemyY < shipY:
            self.enemyY += 0
        elif self.enemyY > shipY:
            self.enemyY -= 0

        if self.enemyX < shipX:
            self.enemyX += 0
        elif self.enemyX > shipX:
        self.enemyX -= 0
```

Comment: The error isn't in the code you list, and the title of the question is wrong - the undefined variable is 'enemyShip1', not 'self'.

Comment: The edit still doesn't show the troublesome code. Look at the code leading to line 145, in particular, where you think you create enemyShip1. Check your spelling and capitalization.

Comment: sorry I copied the wrong error message,edited-fixed

Comment: And where is the code where this error is reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indent these lines:

```
if self.currentState2==1:

elif self.currentState2==0:
```

They are not considered part of the function def since they have the same indentation as the function name.

Comment: cheers,after this module im done with python..I'll stick wtih C++ & Java

Comment: Not just those lines, but all the code that is supposed to be in them as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is incorrect in the method `calculateNextPosition`. As a result, the series of if statements are executed in the body of the class (not the method), where `self` isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is off. The if statement is outside of the method you think it's in.

Answer (score 1):

Check your indentation - the condition is on the same level as your function definition. In other words it's not inside the function so technically yes - self is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You might just have an indentation error.

Since `self` is implicitly passed as the first argument to an instance method, if you have something like:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self):
        return "foo called"
```

...then it's fine, because `self` is a local variable for the method.  However, if you goof up the indentation like this:

```
class A(object):
    def bar(self):
        if self.x == 1:
            do_stuff()
    if self.x == 2:
        do_something_else()
```

...that second `self.x` will cause the error, because `self` doesn't mean anything outside the scope of the function.